# If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$, does $ab \mid c^2$ automatically hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I ask this question with [this comment as context in mind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587560/if-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-prime-q-satisfying-k-1-t#comment9669274_4587560).

So here goes:

> If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$, does $ab \mid c^2$ automatically hold?

**MY ATTEMPT AT A PROOF**

$a \mid c$ means that there exists an integer $k$ such that $c = ka$.

$b \mid c$ means that there exists an integer $l$ such that $c = lb$.

This means that there exists an integer $m = kl$ such that
$$c^2 = c \times c = {ka} \times {lb} = \left(k \times l\right) \cdot {ab} = m\cdot{ab}.$$

It follows that $ab \mid c^2$.

**INQUIRY**

> Is my proof correct?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut!  (Yes, I am aware of that caveat.)  Please write out an answer, to that effect, so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue, and furthermore, so that I could upvote and then accept your answer.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine. Please do not use it that way.

Comment: Please delete the question since it is a dupe of a FAQ. It adds nothing new to the site but clutters serach results.

Comment: @BillDubuque: "It adds nothing new to the site..." I beg to disagree.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. (it's not in your question, but note that in general, you can't conclude $ab\,|\,c$, unless $a$ and $b$ are coprime)